# How to find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{(s+1)^2(s+2)}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I would need a little help in finding the inverse Laplace transform of the function:
$$f(s)=\frac{s}{(s+1)^2(s+2)}.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: es así? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+s%2F%28%28%E3%80%96+s%2B1%29%E3%80%97%5E2+%28s%2B2%29%29&lk=4&num=1

Comment: Sugiero que intentes descomposicion en fracciones parciales del denominador. (I suggest you try partial fraction decomposition of the denominator). Como sugerencia personal, no se suelen aceptar preguntas en otro idioma que el ingles en este sitio, es mejor que intentes escribir en ingles para que no cierren tu pregunta. (On a personal note, questions in a language other than english are not usually accepted on this site, it is better that you try to write in english so that your question will not be closed down)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, disculpa lo del idioma.

Comment: @MarioM. If you're not completely sure about your english, you could use google translate to translate your question, and add your detailed question in spanish, adding the tag "translation request".

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** recall that:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+a}\right)=e^{-ax},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s+a)^2}\right) = xe^{-ax} $$
and apply a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** the partial fraction decomposition could begin with something like:

$$ \frac{s}{(s+1)^2(s+2)} = \frac{2s+1}{(s+1)^2} + \frac{-2}{s+2} $$

Now you continue from here.

Comment: thank so much  your kind help